# INTELIJ terminal only showing directory instead of running a command prompt

Tags: java, terminal, java.util.scanner, command-prompt, intelinde

Sorry if it is a dumb question, but i was running my code perfectly and the terminal was reacting when i ran my program.

After turning my laptop off and on I cant seem to get it to show my SOP commands in the terminal. All i get is the directory of where my program is saved in.

[image: I have a couple of Scanner prompts that are not coming out in the terminal/ command prompt]

Comment: The System.out.println output is not in the Terminal window; you'll find it in the Run window which will be created when you click on Run. Alternatively, you can find your output in the Terminal window if you run the application from the command line, e.g. by typing java -jar [whatever-it's-called]. The Terminal window is really just a command line (saving you from having to run a separate Command Prompt window).

Answer (score 0):

right click on projet in your case and then 
right click on "Lab2" and click 'open in terminal'

Answer (score 0):

Because `Terminal` shows the command prompt in which you can write your commands.

If you run your code, you'll probably have a `Run` button around the `Terminal` button. Click on `Run` or `Debug` whichever button is showing and there you will see your output.

(You can optionally do the traditional `javac filename.java` and `java classname` inside the terminal to see your output too if you can't find the `Run` button, which I think will be somewhere near by)

[image: Terminal button next to the Run button]